# Gmail API Android mail receiving

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am using the **Gmail API** for Android in order to send and receive mails on a user's device.

Now as the phone is an Android device, it is ought to have the Gmail App.

When I receive the mail and notify the user about the mail, the user is already notified for the same through the Gmail app, so is there a way that I can notify the user before the Gmail app has done so?

P.S.: I am using an **AlarmManager** that reads the mails received after an interval of 1 minute, is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Doubtful, but maybe you can send it at the same time. [GCM topics](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) might help for immediate notifications. You don't have to poll for whether or not there are mails received, but on the serverside you can simple send notifications everytime there's a new mail. The messages will be received by any users subscribed to the topic. Might be a lot of work and honestly, it sounds like what you already have is good for a mail app.

Comment: @Andy But checking for mail every 1 minute through the AlarmManager leads to a heavy data usage even if the user has not received any mails. Is there some solution to this?

Comment: Do you solve that issue? How can we receive a mail using android programming? I tried but it does not success. Could you suggest to me the solution?